# MS Access: DoCmd.RunSQL dice necesitar una instrucción SQL, pese a que está presente

Tags: sql, vba, ms-access

Quiero hacer una consulta sql, pero al ejecutarla con `DoCmd.RunSQL` me dice que necesita una instrucción SQL para que funcione. ¿Alguien sabe qué está mal?

Tengo otras consultas hechas igual y sí que funcionan, los nombres de las tablas y los campos están bien.

```
    Dim SQL3 As String
    SQL3 = "SELECT Unidades FROM Producto WHERE ID_Producto=14683"
    DoCmd.RunSQL SQL3
```

El error es:

```
Se ha producido el error '2342' en tiempo de ejecución: La acción EjecutarSQL requiere como argumento una instrucción SQL
```

Comment: podrias mostrar el error tal como aparece? pegalo como texto, no como una imagen...

Comment: usa el boton [edit] y pone el error en la pregunta... pero ese sql esta correcto

Comment: El error 2342 que mencionas suele generarse por falta de un selector, este link tiene mas información https://access-excel.tips/access-docmd-runsql-error-2342/ espero te sirva

Comment: Funciona, pero lo que me hace es crear una consulta, lo que necesito es que me devuelva un valor para guardarlo en una variable sin que me cree una consulta en la base de datos.

Comment: Lo que menciona @Kevtho es relevante porque indica que no se puede usarRunSQL para hacer SELECT.

Comment: Cierto, me debí saltar ese dato al leer y es que no se puede usar RunSQL para un select. Lo solucione haciendo con Recordset y ya funciona.

Comment: Voy a reeditar tu pregunta.. En este sitio esta muy bien visto que contestes tu propia pregunta, en la parte de abajo, donde dice respuestas!!!!!

Answer (score 1):

El error se produce porque:

```
Dim SQL3 As String
SQL3 = "SELECT Unidades FROM Producto WHERE ID_Producto=14683"
DoCmd.RunSQL SQL3
```

El método .RunSql únicamente ejecuta consultas de acción. O lo que es lo mismo, actúa sobre la BBDD actualizándola UPDATE, insertando, INSERT etc... no funciona usando un SELECT

Para poder capturar en una variable algún valor, debes instanciar un objeto RecordSet y recorrer el resultado (ten en cuenta que esto se debe a que el resultado de la consulta puede devolver varios registros a la vez)

Con este código:

```
    Dim dbs As DAO.Database
    Dim rsSQL As DAO.Recordset
    Dim strSQL As String
    
    Set dbs = CurrentDb
    
    'Open a snapshot-type Recordset based on an SQL statement
    strSQL = "SELECT * FROM Table1 WHERE Field2 = 33"
    Set rsSQL = dbs.OpenRecordset(strSQL, dbOpenSnapshot)
```

Ya tienes creado el objeto Recordset en rsSQL. Luego solo tienes que recorrerlo con With y capturar los valores que desees:
Como puedes ver, dentro del Loop, se recorrerá toda la consulta, tanto si hay un resultado como si hay varios. Los campos se indican como ![campo1]. En el ejemplo se editan, y se actualiza, pero tú puedes únicamente leer y  asignar a una variable el valor de un campo Mivariable = ![campo1] (eso sí, define bien el tipo de variable, ya que podría no ser compatible con el dato leído...)

```
' If the recordset is empty, exit. 
   If rstEmployees.EOF Then Exit Sub 
 
   With rsSQL 
      Do Until .EOF 
         .Edit 
         ![ReportsTo] = 5 
         ![Title] = "Temporary" 
          .Update 
         .MoveNext 
      Loop 
   End With
```

Para finalizar, ya fuera del Loop, y no menos importante, debes destruir la instancia... primero se cierra el objeto y luego se destruye la instancia

```
rsSQL.Close
Set rsSQL = Nothing
```